# How to turn a Windows 10 PC into a web server

Tags: webserver, wamp

I have been Googling this without success.  I am trying to set up a web server on Windows 10, but the more I look into it, the more confused I get.

What do I need to set up or install first?

It would be best if you could point me to a website for help.

The code I'm trying to upload uses Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a Google search for how to install a WAMP server. This solution will be fine for development, but I would recommend using a service provider, if you want to serve to the Internet. They handle a lot of the security concerns involved with web hosting for you, and you will also get email for the domain.

Comment: Thank you Strom I feedback to my boss on this.